# Split alphanumeric string to array containing the alphabet and numeric characters separately

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, split

I'm looking to find a way to split an alphanumeric string like

```
"Foo123Bar"
```

into an array that contains it like so

```
array[0] = "Foo"
array[1] = "123"
array[2] = "Bar"
```

I'm not sure what the best way to achieve this is, especially because the strings I'm comparing follow no specific pattern as far as which is first, alphabet or numbers, or how many times they each appear. For example it could look like any of the following:

```
"Foo123Bar"
"123Bar"
"Foobar123"
"Foo123Bar2"
```

I'm trying to find out if there is a more efficient way of doing this other than splitting the string character by character and checking to see if it's numeric.

Comment: What should be the result of `"Foobar123"` , should it be `Foo`, `bar` and `123` or `Foobar` and `123`

Comment: The result of `"Foobar123"` should be `"Foobar"` and `"123"`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
string input = "Foo123Bar";
var array = Regex.Matches(input, @"\D+|\d+")
                 .Cast<Match>()
                 .Select(m => m.Value)
                 .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you will get around checking every character of the string.
You could try something like this:

```
string[] SplitMyString(string s)
{
  if( s.Length == 0 )
    return new string[0];

  List<string> split = new List<string>(1);
  split.Add("");

  bool isNumeric = s[0] >= '0' && s[0] <= '9';
  foreach(char c in s)
  {
    bool AddString = false;
    if( c >= '0' && c <= '9' )
    {
      AddString = !isNumeric;
      isNumeric = true;
    }
    else
    {
      AddString = isNumeric;
      isNumeric = false;
    }
    if( AddString )
        split.Add(c.ToString());
    else
      split[split.Count-1] += c;
  }
  return split.ToArray();
}
```